# any element in XML schema blocks XQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, xsd, xquery, xquery-sql

I have the following XML Schema:

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION test AS '
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="PointConf">
    <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="GlobalFlags">
              <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                      <xsd:element name="Order" type="OrderType"/>
                      <xsd:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
              </xsd:complexType>  
            </xsd:element>           
          </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:complexType name="OrderType">
    <xsd:attribute name="value" type="xsd:int" />
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
'
GO
```

Then I use it in this way:

```
DECLARE @xml xml(test)

SET @xml='<PointConf>
  <GlobalFlags>    
    <Order value="1" />
  </GlobalFlags>

</PointConf>'

SELECT @xml.value('(/PointConf/GlobalFlags/Order/@value)[1]','int')
```

`SELECT` gives me the following error:

```
XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type '(xs:int | xdt:anyAtomicType *) ?'
```

Without the `xsd:any` element in the schema the code above works without any errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the select to work by using the statement

```
SELECT @xml.value('string(/PointConf[1]/GlobalFlags/Order[1]/@value)','int')
```

I understand the requirement for the `[1]` index on the Order node, as this can be a list, however I don't see why its required for the `PointConf` node.

The `[1]` needs to be used at the actual level where a list exists to restrict that list to a single return value

The `string(...)` turns the node set into a string (or empty string). I think this helps with the `xsd:any` although I'm not completely sure why - something to do with handling the possibility of the node `Order` being missing completely I think.

---

Update:

Investigating further:

`SELECT @xml.value('string((/PointConf/GlobalFlags/Order/@value)[1])','int')`

also works.

So its just the string function that's required to make it work in this instance.

Comment: Isn't `(/PointConf/GlobalFlags/Order/@value)[1]` already gives me only one value from the resulting set? What the reason for using `string`?

Comment: On testing more, you can use that xpath inside the string function to make it work. As I said in my original answer, I'm not completely sure about why `string()` works, but I think its something to do with turning a fail into an empty string.